# Как реализовать onBackPressed во Фрагменте?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

В своем приложении использую архитектуру `Single Activity`.
Есть два фрагмента. Во втором фрагменте, если были внесены изменения в полях, при нажатии на кнопку "Назад" в `ToolBar`, необходимо вызвать `AlertDialog`.
Я попытался реализовать это через `onOptionsItemSelected`, но данный код не возымел результата:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                .setMessage("Были внесены изменения.")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Да", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //действия, если да
                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Нет", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //действия, если нет
            }
        }).create().show();
    }
}
```

Немного почитав по этому поводу, я наткнулся на один вариант. В нем говорится, что нужно создать интерфейс `IOnBackPressed`, затем переопределить метод `onBackPressed` в `Activity` и в завершении реализовать метод интерфейса во фрагменте. Первые два пункта не вызвали затруднений, в отличии от последнего.
Создание интерфейса:

```
public interface IOnBackPressed {
    boolean onBackPressed();
}
```

Переопределение `onBackPressed` в `Activity`

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_container);
       if (!(fragment instanceof IOnBackPressed) || !((IOnBackPressed) fragment).onBackPressed()) {
          super.onBackPressed();
       }
    } ...
}
```

Реализация метода интерфейса во Фрагменте:
Никак не могу понять, что за загадочное `myCondition`.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements IOnBackPressed{
   @Override
   public boolean onBackPressed() {
       if (myCondition) {
            //action not popBackStack
            return true; 
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в сложившейся ситуации или подскажите другое решение задачи. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы должны вернуть `true` или `false` из вашего метода `onBackPressed()`.

- если вы вернете `true` то `onBackPressed()` обработает фрагмент и тот код который будет в `Activity` в `onBackPressed()` не выполнится.
- если вы вернете `false` то тот код который будет у вас в фрагменте проигнорируется. А выполнится код из `Activity`.

`myCondition` - это просто любой ваш предикат по которому функция поймет стоит ли обрабатывать это действие во фрагменте. Вы можете и не вызывать никаких `if(myCondition)`, а всегда возвращать true, но если вам нужна какая-то логика которую должна в каких-то случаях обрабатывать `Activity`, то вы должны вернуть `false`.

Comment: большое спасибо за ответ! Т.е. в моем случае `myCondition`, это метод который проверяет были ли изменения во фрагменте или нет, я правильно Вас понял?

Comment: Я не очень понимаю, что это у вас. Но это сугубо ваше условие в котором вы говорите кто будет обрабатывать нажатие "назад" активити или фрагмент.

Comment: Вы можете всегда возвращать true и его будет обрабатывать только фрагмент или всегда false и все будет работать как будто вы и не реализовывали ничего этого

Comment: Еще раз спасибо Вам большое!

Comment: Пожалуйста=)...

Answer (score 2):

Можно вот так обрабатывать `OnBackPressed` во фрагменте. Добавить в `onViewCreated`.

`Kotlin`:

```
val callback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            // обработайте здесь
        }
    }

 activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner, callback)
```

`Java`:

```
   OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true ) {
    @Override
    public void handleOnBackPressed() {
        // обработайте здесь
    }
};
requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(getViewLifecycleOwner(), callback);
```

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это должно выглядеть на языке `Java`?

Comment: большое спасибо! Хороший вариант.